# How to add new relic java agent to a heroku war

Tags: java, heroku, war, newrelic, procfile

I am facing issue to add java agent to heroku WAR.

Our procfile looks as below,

web: `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

I am following this link to setup newrelic on heroku

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/heroku/java-agent-heroku

but this talks only about jar.